# Is there a way to edit the look of this mp3 file?

Tags: ios, mp3, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMessageComposeViewController to share an mp3 file.

I would like to know if there is a way I can add a custom image to this file instead of the way it looks. If possible any other customizations like changing colors would be great also.

Please check the image for more of a visual explaining my question.

[image]

Comment: @Rashwan L Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an Apple-supplied Cocoa framework: `MFMessageComposeViewController`, and Apple doesn't give you a way to override or customize appearance-related functionality on most of these frameworks.  This is usually done to enhance the end user's experience across all iOS apps.

In most cases, if you are not satisfied with the Apple-supplied functionality, you can write your own.  However, in this case, since you are dealing with Messaging / SMS, you are stuck with what Apple gives you, for the sake of security.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I am stuck with the file as is.